# SQL Server Counting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
select col1, sum( col2 ), count( col3 )
from table1
group by col1
order by col1
```

which returns something like this

```
col1
dept1
dept2
dept3

col2
10
20
30

col3
2
3
4
```

Without a stored procedure, is it possible to get a total column below the results generated by the original query?

i.e.

```
col1
dept1
dept2
dept3
total

col2
10
20
30
60

col3
2
3
4
9
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [ROLLUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx):

```
;with Table1 as (
    select 'dept1' as col1, 5 as col2,1 as col3
    union all
    select 'dept1', 5 as col2, 1 as col3
    union all
    select 'dept2',10,1
    union all
    select 'dept2',5,1
    union all
    select 'dept2',5,1
    union all
    select 'dept3',10,1
    union all
    select 'dept3',5,1
    union all
    select 'dept3',5,1
    union all
    select 'dept3',10,1
)
select COALESCE(col1,'total'), sum( col2 ), count( col3 )
from table1
group by col1
with rollup
order by COALESCE(col1,'ZZZZZ')
```

Results:

```
(No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)
dept1               10                  2
dept2               20                  3
dept3               30                  4
total               60                  9
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the keyword `WITH ROLLUP` on your `GROUP BY` clause

Answer (score 1):

yep:

```
select col1, sum(col2), count(col3)
from table1
group by col1
union all
select 'totals', sum(col2), count(1) from table1
order by col1
```

Comment: Hope there is no department named 'Tutorial', that would mess up your example